# What event handler should i use for modal form to send an email

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events, bootstrap-modal

I am creating a web app and i want to send a message through a form to my email using EmailJS(https://www.emailjs.com). They have a simple way though which you can send an email to yourself when a form has been loaded on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       (function() {
        // https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin/integration
        emailjs.init('YOUR_USER_ID');
    })();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    **window.onload =** function() {
        document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // generate a five digit number for the contact_number variable
            this.contact_number.value = Math.random() * 100000 | 0;
            // these IDs from the previous steps
            emailjs.sendForm('contact_service', 'contact_form', this)
                .then(function() {
                    console.log('SUCCESS!');
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log('FAILED...', error);
                });
        });
    }
</script>
```

In my case i am using a modal form with bootstrap and in their case tutorial they have included only one case when the form has already been loaded on the screen the **windows.onload**.For the form that has already been loaded (on screen form) its working . My question is what handler should i use and how if i am to use a modal form since it is loaded after the onload has already occurred.

Here is my screen snippet of the code

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
    
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
           <title>Form Testing</title>
     
    
           <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"          rel="stylesheet" />
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js">     </script>
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
           <script type="text/javascript">
               (function () {
                  emailjs.init("user_p07SKunpARYp4aowW97yr");
                })();
             </script>
    
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function () {
                    document.getElementById('modal-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                       event.preventDefault();
                      // generate a five digit number for the contact_number variable
                      this.contact_number.value = Math.random() * 100000 | 0;
                      // these IDs from the previous steps
                        emailjs.sendForm('service_k34ck3j', 'contact_form', this)
                           .then(function () {
                               console.log('SUCCESS!');
                           }, function (error) {
                              console.log('FAILED...', error);
                           });
                     });
            }
        </script>
       
    
        </head>
        <body>
            
    
    <form class="modal fade" id="modal-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-dialogLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-dialogLabel">User Details</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
    
                    <!-- actual form markup -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" placeholder="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="user_email" type="email" class="form-control" id="field2" placeholder="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="user_number" type="number" class="form-control" id="field2" placeholder="number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea type="text" id="form8" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="4" name="message"
                            placeholder="Example : how much does it cost to roof a 10*20 house using harvey tiles"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /actual form markup -->
    
                </div>
    
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="save" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-form">
        Open modal form
    </

button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I assume `**window.onload =** function() {` was an attempt to bold the code, rather than those `*`s actually being in your code?

Comment: yes it was a mistake ofcourse but i believe the question is clear

Answer (score 0):

Since u r using bootstrap, you can use bootstrap modal events - `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events`

For triggering function after modal load, you can use event 'shown.bs.modal'

```
  $("#modal-form").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    alert('The modal is fully shown.');
  });
```